# Getting Invalid Identifier for Snowflake Sequence Nextval

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sequence, nextval

I created a Sequence batch_id_seq in Snowflake. But when I am running the query "select batch_id_seq.nextval" from outside snowflake environment, I am getting the below error:

SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 7
invalid identifier 'BATCH_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL'

The query is working fine from within Snowflake Worksheet. Can anyone let me know what needs to be done to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you are at different schema `SELECT CURRENT_SCHEMA()`:

```
select batch_id_seq.nextval
```

=>

```
select <schema_name_here>.batch_id_seq.nextval
```

Comment: This is probably correct. It's also possible that you're in the wrong database, or you're using a role that doesn't have the proper grants.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check if the role you are using has the proper rights and grants to be able to access the schema.